# Replace windows8 with ubuntu from dual-boot

Tags: installation, dual-boot, virtualbox, windows-8, uefi

I have an Acer Aspire 5349, came with win7 preinstalled, but Win8 installed as only OS, so none of that UEFI crap.

Recently installed ubuntu 13.04 as dual-boot (NOT with wubi) but now I want to remove my win8 partition(around 420GB now) and move my ubuntu partiton (only about 80GB) over so i can get my full 500GB (technically) for just ubuntu, and make it my only OS.

Is that even possible since the windows 8 partition was there first?

also, I want to convert my windows 8 installation to a virtual PC in ubuntu, so i can still use it when i need the windows applications that can't be run in ubuntu. is there any way i can go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way i can go about doing that?

No, you cannot convert your Win8 into a virtual Windows inside Ubuntu.
However, you can remove your current Windows, then create a virtual Windows machine in Ubuntu (eg via [VirtuaBox](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/)).

> Is that even possible since the windows 8 partition was there first?

Yes. To remove your current Windows:

- Backup your Windows documents.
- Boot into Ubuntu, install and run [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller), select `Windows`, apply. This will format your Windows partition (NTFS by default, but you can select EXT in the advanced options), and update your bootloader.

[image]

- Reboot and check that you can still boot onto Ubuntu.
- Optionally, you can use [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) to manage (resize, change the format...) the freed partition.

Comment: okay, but does that then extend my ubuntu installation to the entire disk, or does that just leave unallocated space and leave my 80GB ubuntu installation alone?

Comment: I edited my answer above.

Comment: It makes sense but what I mean is, does that then make my Ubuntu have access to the whole drive, or still only the 80 i assigned to it?  Does that move my partition across the whole drive or just leave unallocated space where the windows 8 was?

Comment: OS-Uninstaller will format the partition into NTFS (or EXT). Not unallocated. Ubuntu can immediately see this partition, and you can use it the way you want. For example, you can put data in it.

Comment: You may try to use Windows as a virtual machine in Ubuntu, with [VirtualBox raw partition access](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk). But Windows might complain that the hardware has changed (because it will see VirtualBox emulated hardware) so it might need reactivation.

Answer (score 2):

login to your windows and backup data. Its wise to backup data on Ubuntu. If anything happens you can recover them.

Then Login to your Ubuntu as usual and open GParted. Delete the Windows partition and let the GParted finish (Power crash will bring disaster so make sure that Power is available). After tha open terminal `(Ctrl+Alt+T)` and type `sudo update-grub` Then Reboot. If all went well, you are on track now we go to final stage

Boot in your Ubuntu DVD/CD/Bootable USB stick and launch GParted. Resize your Ubuntu partitions and wait Gparted to finish. Reboot back to HDD. You are done!

Comment: On the final step does a USB stick work as well instead of a CD/DVD? That's how I installed Ubuntu to begin with.

Comment: Whether you boot from CD/DVD or USB stick makes no difference. I'll update the answer!